# Invoking a DatePickerDialog does not change data

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to make the following projekt:
Start Activity has 4 buttons.
1. First Button just opens an Information Dialog (onClick0)
2. Second Button opens a DatePickerDialog and allows me to Set a Date. (onClick1)
3. Third Button opens a Dialog that shows me the date i entered (onClick2).
4. Fourth Button just opens an About Dialog. (onClick3)

The problem is that after the first Date set, the Dialog that i open pressing the Third Button   show me always the First Date set i did.

What am i doing wrong?
Please help me :)

### MainActivity code:

```
package boy.girl;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DateFormat fmtDateAndTime=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
Calendar dateAndTime=Calendar.getInstance();

int mYear,mMonth,mDay;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick0(View v) 
{ 
    showDialog(0); 
}

public void onClick1(View v)
{ 
     new DatePickerDialog(this, d,
             dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
             dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
             dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
     .show();
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
Integer.toString(mDay)+" "+Integer.toString(mMonth)+" "+Integer.toString(mYear),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
};

public void onClick2(View v) 
{ 
    showDialog(2); 
}

public void onClick3(View v) { showDialog(3); }


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
    case 0:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.infobox);
        builder.setTitle("Title Information");
        builder.setMessage("Information text...");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,    int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ok clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                    }
                });
    return builder.create();

            case 2: 

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Results")
    .setMessage(Integer.toString(mDay)+" "+Integer.toString(mMonth)+
" "+Integer.toString(mYear))
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ok clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
            }
        }
    ).create();

    case 3: 
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("About")
        .setMessage("About this company and App version")
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ok clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
            }
        }
    ).create();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateDialog` is called only once. Therefore it is always showing the data from the first time you opened it.

You need to update the message in `onPrepareDialog`. That should get it working for you.

PS: onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog are deprecated in ICS, and also a little buggy in ICS. Try using the new APIs if possible.

Edit:

Keep your code as it is, just add the following -

```
 @Override
  protected void onPrepareDialog(int dialogId, Dialog dialog, Bundle args) {
    if(dialogId==2){
      ((AlertDialog)dialog).setMessage(Integer.toString(mDay)+" "+Integer.toString(mMonth)+
        " "+Integer.toString(mYear));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain me how to update message in onPrepareDialog ?

Comment: Edited my answer to give an example.